# My EditButton() doesn't work properly after modifying the list in another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

My `editbutton()` works just fine. But every time when I go to the `AddView()` Screen to add an item to the list and come back to the MainView my Editbutton doesn't show the red circles to delete items.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var array: [Person] = [Person(name: "Tim", age: 23), Person(name: "Marie", age: 24)]

    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        NavigationView{
            
            List{
                ForEach(array) {item in
                    Text(item.name)
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    array.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
            EditButton()
            NavigationLink("AddView", destination: AddView(array: $array))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddView: View{
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    @Binding var array: [Person]
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack {
            TextField("Type here", text: $text)
            Button("Add") {
                array.append(Person(name: text, age: 14))
            }
        }
    }
}




    
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Even when I change one of the items "manually" the EditButton still doesn't work properly.

Comment: I added 1. '@Environment(\.dismiss) var presMode' and called 'presMode()' in den Button.

It works somehow, why?